# Diifference between sfp/sfp+ ports and unified ports

Tags: switch, interface, sfp

there is something I don't understand. Some switches have SFP ports, it means that you can connect fiber or rj-45 cables I believe?

Some switches like Nexus 5600 have unified ports. So they can support fiber and rj-45 (and FCOE).

What's the difference between SFP and unified, just the FCOE support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unified ports allow you to move from an existing segregated platform approach where you choose LAN and SAN port optionsto transition to a single, unified fabric that istransparent and consistent with existing practices and management software. You will need to swap SFPs (for now, at least) and reconfigure the port, and you must cycle/reset the module in which the ports reside in order to switch personality. Personally, I think the Unified Port functionality is extremely useful.